# SSRS report "unable to load client print control"

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

We're using SQL Server 2008 for a (third-party) web app, and they utilise SSRS for reporting.

Recently, so I'm assuming this is related in some way to an MS patch, whenever we click on the "print" icon in a report we get an error popup:

```
Message from webpage
Unable to load client print control.
```

- The web server is Windows Server 2003 R2 x32
- The SSRS server is Windows SQL Server 2008 10.0.2531.0
- The SQL server is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)
- The clients are Windows 7 and Windows XP

All the servers are up-to-date according to Windows Update.

The SSRS server also has the "Security Update for Report Viewer Redistributable 2008 Service Pack 1 (KB971119) installed.

Answer (score 3):

The report redist must also be installed on any application/web servers if the app is using the report viewer .net control.

Users also need admin rights to install the activeX in xp.

We automate the installation of these component to all users - similar to this:  http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/client-side-printing-silent-deployment-of-rsclientPrint.aspx

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brianhartman/client-print-fails-to-load-after-microsoft-update-956391) was an enlightening post when I had this problem.