# SSRS reports print button missing in IE 8

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, ssrs-2008-r2

Seems like this is broken again ([SSRS report "unable to load client print control"](https://serverfault.com/questions/177268/ssrs-report-unable-to-load-client-print-control) and [SQL 2008 SP2 RsClientPrint ActiveX - "Unable to load client print control"](https://serverfault.com/questions/230292/sql-2008-sp2-rsclientprint-activex-unable-to-load-client-print-control)).  We updated all of our Windows 7 clients last Friday and it looks like the mighty "Unable to load client print control" has returned since then.  Anyone aware of possible problems with the latest batch of Windows Updates?

Answer (score 0):

Wild goose chase as someone disabled the client printing in Report Manager.